# How should I take the sign or check isnull() of a column in pandas eval/query function?

Tags: pandas

Given a pandas dataframe, how should I do sth like the following?

```
df.eval('B * sign(A)')
df.query('A.notnull()')
```

It is not letting me because sign(A) and A.notnull() is not recognized.

Comment: Please add a small example dataset.

Answer (score 3):

[`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval) can only handle a small subset of expressions and `sign` is not included.

However, with some mental gymnastics you can re-create the sign function. Typically you could just use `A/abs(A)` to reproduce `np.sign`, but for `0` that implementation returns `NaN`, while `np.sign(0) == 0`. Instead we will work with Boolean Series to get the `0` correct. If you want to return `NaN` 
for `sign(NaN)`, consistent with `np.sign`, we need even more of a hack.

```
# B * np.sign(A)
df.eval('B * ((A != 0) - 2*(A < 0))')

# With proper NaN handling
df.eval('B * ((A != 0) - 2*(A < 0)) * arcsin((A != A) + sin(1))')
```

---

```
# Sample Data
          A         B
0 -1.588994  0.856149
1  0.000000  1.461134
2  1.028567 -0.610840
3  0.869345 -1.707041
4 -0.041404  1.322980
5 -0.287458  1.047247
6 -0.628855  1.235757
7 -1.224231  0.863408
8  2.430871  1.509066
9  0.602590  0.529180

(df.eval('B * ((A != 0) - 2*(A < 0))') == df.B*np.sign(df.A)).all()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import numpy as np

df['B']*np.sign(df['A'].to_numpy())

df[~df['A'].isna()]
```

As in the comments, remark that `np.sign(0)=0`