# Calling round(), ceiling(), floor(), min(), max() in pandas eval

Tags: python, pandas, eval

As title says, Is there a way to support round, ceiling, min, max, floor functions in pandas eval.

DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numexpr as ne
op_d = {'ID': [1, 2,3],'V':['F','G','H'],'AAA':[0,1,1],'E':[102014,112019,122017] ,'D':['2019/02/04','2019/02/01','2019/01/01'],'DD':['2019-12-01','2016-05-31','2015-02-15'],'CurrentRate':[7.5,2,2],'NoteRate':[2,3,3],'BBB':[0,00,4],'Q1':[2,8,00],'Q2':[3,5,7],'Q3':[5,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=op_d)
```

abs() and sqrt() function works with pandas eval. i.e.

```
df.eval('TT = abs(sqrt(Q1+Q2)-Q2)',inplace=True)
df
```

can anyone suggest how to access rest of the functions in eval? I also tried 'local_dict' in eval to see if I can define custom functions and call them but it didn't work.

Note:

1. Arithmetic operations inside these functions are necessary (i.e. sum, multiplication, div of two columns).
2. I am aware of issues around usage of 'eval' functions and taking necessary measurements.

Comment: did you not do `sum` already? Also  `*` for multiplication, `/` for division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of 'py_expression_eval' libary, I was able to work out arithmatic operations inside user defined functions.

```
from py_expression_eval import Parser
parser = Parser()

dct = {'Q1':df['Q1'],'Q2':df['Q2'],'max':max1,'round':getround}
df['check']=parser.parse('round(Q1/Q2)').evaluate(dct)
```

library source: https://github.com/Axiacore/py-expression-eval

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2):

### You can't

`DataFrame.eval` only [supports a limited set of math operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#supported-syntax)

> Arithmetic operations except for the left shift (<<) and right shift
>   (>>) operators, e.g., `df + 2 * pi / s ** 4 % 42 - the_golden_ratio`
>
> Math functions: sin, cos, exp, log, expm1, log1p, sqrt, sinh, cosh, tanh, arcsin, arccos, arctan, arccosh, arcsinh, arctanh, abs, arctan2 and log10.

If it's not on that list you can't call it beacause "**Function calls other than math functions [are not allowed syntax]"**

---

That being said, it *might* be possible to implement some of those functions in terms of more basic operations. [Here I've implemented an `eval` equivalent of `np.sign`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399572/how-should-i-take-the-sign-or-check-isnull-of-a-column-in-pandas-eval-query-fu/59399972#59399972). But IMO that obfuscates the operation far too much and isn't very useful, so really you need to move away from `eval`

Comment: What are the other options here? Basically, I am getting expression at run time which I need to perform on a csv file and add columns based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can do `round`,`min`, and `max` the way you want. If you set the backend engine in `eval` to Python (although I think it is rather slow). Seems to have been there since Pandas v1.0 at least.

```
df.eval('TTR = TT.round(2)', engine='python', inplace=True)
df.eval('TT_min = TT.min()', engine='python', inplace=True)
df.eval('TT_max = TT.max()', engine='python', inplace=True)
df
```

For `floor` and `ceil` operations you have to figure something else out (e.g. using `apply`).